# GRMustache formatted numbers, or an HTML Template Engine with Number Formatting in iOS

Tags: html, ios, template-engine, kvc

I'm not sure how to best go about this.  I've tried solving this my own way, [but failed so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523448/ruby-style-string-interpolation-with-ios-nsregularexpression).  I tried using GRMustache, only to realize that I'm trying to display `float`s that just look hideous in the template I'm trying to use.

Basically, I have a model that I'm trying to have output as HTML via a template.  Ideally, I just put the variable names/keypaths into the template and the template just gets parsed with the actual values (pretty much) rendered in place.  But, the model I'm using uses floats for all its calculations and I'd really like them rendered as comma-separated integer strings (e.g. `(float)9382.233325` => `"9,382"`).

I can't seem to find any documentation in GRMustache that covers a situation like this, but I imagine this can't be an uncommon requirement.  Does anyone know how to do this with GRMustache or through some other technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of GRMustache.

There isn't, and there will never be any float formatting features in GRMustache, because there is already a perfectly well suited tool in the OS: NSNumberFormatter.

Since you're giving to GRMustache your model objects, here is my advice:

Declare a category on your model, and add a specific method for each of your formatted value:

```
@interface MYModel(GRMustache)
// name would match your original value property name
- (NSString *)formattedValue;
@end
```

In the implementation file, use a NSNumberFormatter:

```
@implementation MYModel(GRMustache)
- (NSString *)formattedValue
{
  // Check the NSNumberFormatter reference for initializing
  // the NSSNumberFormatter for your desired output.
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSSNumberFormatter ...]; 
  return [formatter stringFromNumber: [self value]];
}
@end
```

Beware creating many NSNumberFormatter instances may be costly. A good practice is to provide a shared method that returns a shared one. The code above is just a hint for the technique.

Finally, in your template, replace `{{value}}` tags with `{{formattedValue}}`.

Happy GRMustache!

Comment: This is excellent, thank you.  I'm wondering, though, it seems a bit tedious to have to create a formatted value method for every single attribute (something like 20-25).  I'm assuming GRMustache tags items can't be messages that take arguments.  Is there perhaps a way to metaprogram something like this for any `formatted<value>`?

Comment: Yes, there is one, with a lambda section {{#format}}{{value}}{{/format}}. Check thoroughly the lambda documentation on the GRMustache page. Now check GRMustacheSection.h, look for the method that returns the inner unprocessed content of the section. You should be able to implement a lambda that extracts the variable name "value" from the template string "{{value}}", and do your processing. Not ideal, I admit, but it would certainly work, with some room for optimization.

Comment: There are many many ways, actually :-) Look also after defining 20-25 static lambdas formatted_value1, formatted_value2, etc which would format the value extracted from the lambda context. Examine the isolated GRMustache helper object in the doc. This would be more verbose, but more clear than the previous technique above, and more readable than the 20-25 properties.

Comment: I went with your {{#format}} block solution, which also helped me understand how sections in general work.  You've built a pretty awesome tool here. Thank you so much!

Comment: Josh, GRMustache 1.9 is out, with built-in support for number formatting. You should check it out, it will certainly make your template less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

GRMustache 1.12 now features a better API for number formatting: https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/sample_code/number_formatting.md